# awk to print text if pattern is meet with nothing under

Tags: awk

The below `awk` is meant to be used for the two possible outcomes of `file` which is `tab delimeted`. Option 1 is that `file` will only contain a header row with nothing under it. Option 2 is `file` will contain the same header row but with rows under it. The `awk` reads `file` and if it is option 1 or header only then `1 0 0 0 0` is printed (with tab seperated). If `file` is option 2 or a header with rows under it nothing is done. There may be more then one `file` in the directory but always the same format.

**file (option1)**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Gene
```

**file (option2)**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Gene
1   1   100 300 xxx
2   2   200 250 yyy
```

**desired output if option 1**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Gene
1   0   0   0   0
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' '{if ($0 ~ /R_Index\tChr\tStart\tEnd\tGene/) {print "1\t0\t0\t0\t0} else {next}}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file

awk -F'\t' '/R_Index\tChr\tStart\tEnd\tGene/{print "1\t0\t0\t0\t0"; next}1' file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1 && $0!="R_Index\tChr\tStart\tEnd\tGene"{NR=0; exit 1}1; 
                   END {if(NR==1){print 1,0,0,0,0; exit 0} exit 1}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

exit status will be only successful if the second line needs to be added, which then triggers updating the file via tmp file.

Comment: And yes, only one hole for the cat and the mouse ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much :).